# manually chop down function parameters, etc. with shortcut

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

IntelliJ (in my case with Kotlin) has a code style property `Function declaration parameters` set to `Chop down if long` by default. This is just what I want, but sometimes I also want to do that manually (not only when formating if it's too long). Is there a shortcut or a way to set one in the IDE?

```kotlin
fun foo(p1: T1, p2: T2) {
    ...
}
```

becomes

```kotlin
fun foo(
    p1: T1,
    p2: T2,
) {
    ...
}
```

The best would be if there was a shortcut similar to folding/expanding code segments, that also work for example on Array declaration.

```kotlin
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

becomes

```kotlin
[
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
]
```

I couldn't find any suitable action, maybe I searched for the wrong terms.

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4]` is not how you write an array in kotlin.

Comment: @Sweeper yes, sorry. I didn't know this is only for annotations parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your cursor on the parameter list, and Option+Enter (on macOS) or Alt+Enter (on Windows). This brings up a context menu like this:

[image]

This is known as [Context Actions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Coding_Assistance__Context_Actions.html). You should select "Put parameters on separate lines".

This also works for *argument lists* when you are calling a method, so you can use this for things like `arrayOf`:

[image]